# Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlCast' to type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nhibernate

I'm using the following c# code:

```
public IList<T> GetAllByExpression(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, int startIndex, int count, Func<T, DateTime> dateTimeSelector)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetSession())
    {
        return session.Query<T>()
            .Where(expression)
            .OrderBy(dateTimeSelector)
            .Skip(startIndex - 1)
            .Take(count)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

**update:**
even the follwoing code throws the same exception:

```
public IList<T> GetAllByExpression(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, int startIndex, int count, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> dateTimeSelector)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetSession())
    {
        return session.Query<T>()
            .Where(expression)
            //.OrderBy(dateTimeSelector)
            //.Skip(startIndex - 1)
            //.Take(count)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

And get Nh error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlCast' to type
>   'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression'.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: may be its the expression you are providing to Where that is failing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I wrote short condition in the expression: as ((a == null)? true : a > b) NH casting fails on that (?)

Comment: Can confirm this is the problem. Had the same issue and rewriting the expression solved the issue. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: For a good example of how to rewrite the code to avoid this error, you can view the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774598/conditional-operator-in-linq-expression-causes-nhibernate-exception

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you miss `Expression<>` over your datetime `dateTimeSelector` predicate.

Comment: tried to comment  all:            .OrderBy(dateTimeSelector)
            .Skip(startIndex - 1)
            .Take(count), and it didn't help

Comment: how your example call looks like?

Comment: The problem was that I wrote short condition in the expression: as ((a == null)? true : a > b)
NH casting fails on that (?)

Comment: Probably. Try something trivial like `a > b` and it should work. When it fails at specific conditions (like yours) it means that there's no obvious translation of the expression to SQL (hibernate linq is not able to handle it).